# Running external EXE from python

Tags: python

I'm running several portable apps from my python app.

Consider the following code:

```
import win32com.shell.shell as w32shell
import os
import sys
import win32process as process

PORTABLE_APP_LOCATION = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe"

#This function runs a portable application:
def runPortable():
    try:
        startObj = process.STARTUPINFO()
        process.CreateProcess(PORTABLE_APP_LOCATION,None,None,None,8,8,None,None,startObj)
        # OR
        #w32shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpFile=PORTABLE_APP_LOCATION)
    except:
        print(sys.exc_info()[0])
runPortable()
```

1) Should I expect any differences in the execution of this code from pythonw or python ?

2) If I change `PORTABLE_APP_LOCATION` to the path to [a portable version of CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/en/download) and use the ShellExecuteEx option instead of CreateProcess, I see the process is started on Windows Task Manager but the actual window of the app isn't visible. This doesn't happen with other EXEs such as a portable version of [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) that do show up after being ran. I assume this difference comes from a property of the executables. Anybody knows what's causing this?

3) Under what terms does Windows prompts the "Are you sure you want to run this EXE"? I believe CDBurnerXP is signed with a certificate but still sometimes Windows pops this question when trying to run this EXE from within python.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

About Your first question , you should pay attention that when executing python code using *pythonw.exe* runtime , your **sys.stdout** buffer is limited to **4096** Bytes and when overflowed will throw an IOError wich you will not see because the code is running windowless .

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie in this field. May be this can help you

use `subprocess.call`, more info [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\\temp\\calc.exe"])
```

or

```
import os
os.system('"C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe"')
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: I am aware of other options to execute files like `os.system` and `subprocess.call`.. This isn't what I asked :/